# hibernate краш при Restrictions.eq

Tags: java, hibernate

при компиляции фрагмента ниже краш

```
List <shop> products = null;
Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(shop.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1));
products =  criteria.list();
```

сам краш:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1968)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1939)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1835)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
```

но проблема присутствует только если поле id, ибо если будет:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "clara"));
```

то все нормально. 
Запись с именем Clara присутствует также как и запись с id равном 1 
Как лечить?

PS
изначально карш было осулволен тем что в коде id обозночался как long если заменить его на int то все нормально, не считая работы с массивами
вариант с массивом

```
int []mas= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        Criteria criteria= session.createCriteria(shop.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", mas));
        products =  criteria.list();
```

краш:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1968)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1939)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1835)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке читать не пробовали? Прямо на первой строчке решение вашей проблемы. Исправьте `1` на `1L`.

Comment: @enzo у меня сейчас в голове такое "чёёёёёёёё...". Ну а серьезно если то как это лечить? ибо а если у меня будет не число а массив чисел? да и число я тоже могу и буду подовать посредством переменной

Comment: @ClaraOswald Даже если так, то ничто не мешает явно скастовать перемменную: `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", (Long)parm));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что вы передаете в выражение `Restrictions.eq("id", 1)` переменную не того типа. Переменная `id` в вашей **Entity**, как следует из текста исключения, имеет тип `Long`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

В языке Java литерал, записанный простым числом, в исходном тексте приложения имеет тип `Integer`. Прочитайте [секцию Literals здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), или возьмите любую книгу с основами языка, например Хорстмана.

`Integer` нельзя кастовать в `Long`. В таких случаях необходимо использовать преобразование явное. Например, `Long.valueOf(int)` или `new Long(int)`.

Для того чтобы передать в приведенный вами пример переменную правильного типа, используйте литерал `1L`.

> Ну а серьезно если то как это лечить? ибо а если у меня будет не число
>   а массив чисел? да и число я тоже могу и буду подовать посредством
>   переменной

Поскольку метод [`eq()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) принимает в качестве значения (`value`) `Object` лечение как ни крути будет заключаться в необходимости следить, чтобы тип переменной соответствовал тому, который вы объявили в **Entity**, а не пихать туда все подряд.

Для получения объекта по `id` есть более простой [метод](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29):

```
MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity) session.get(MyEntity.class, id)
```

Comment: а что с вариантом где используется массив значений? там уже в коде исправлено что id имеет значение int а не long

Comment: Метод `eq()` в этом случае не походит. Используйте `Restrictions.in("id", ids)`. Массив перед этим преобразуйте в `List<Long>`.